# Could not autowire field while inserting data into the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Question title may be same, but I tried to solve this error by looking at previous answers, but nothing happen. I'm getting following error while insert data into the database. Tables are created, but there is an error while inserting data into the database.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'InitDbService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.app.flight.repo.RoleRepository com.app.flight.service.InitDbService.roleRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#397030fe' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#397030fe': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
```

This is my `Role.java` entity class

```
@Entity
public class Role {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Integer id;
   private String name;

   (getters and setters)
```

This is `RoleRepository.java` interface

```
package com.app.flight.repo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.app.flight.entity.Role;

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {

}
```

This is service class `InitDbService.java`

```
package com.app.flight.service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.app.flight.entity.Role;
import com.app.flight.repo.RoleRepository;

@Transactional
@Service
public class InitDbService {

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        Role roleUser = new Role();
        roleUser.setName("ROLE_USER");
        roleRepository.save(roleUser);

        Role roleAdmin= new Role();
        roleAdmin.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        roleRepository.save(roleAdmin);

    }
}
```

This is applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.7.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.flight">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<jdbc:embedded-database type="HSQL" id="dataSource"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="emf">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.app.flight.entity"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.app.flight.repo"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It expects that the EntityManagerFactory has a specific name in that case "entityManagerFactory". You defined a custom name "emf". I assume the problem is resolved if you adapt the entry in the xml file.

Comment: **It works, Great**. Thank you so much. May I know, why I can't use it as `emf` ?

Comment: Mark the answer as correct, that it is visible as resolved.
Spring uses convention over configuration for many things to make it easier to use. 
Spring boot can configure the entitymanager complelty on its own. You only do it manually if you need something custom.

Comment: If your interersted how to do this via bean configuration you can check out the following -> https://github.com/mh-dev/blog_springBoot-jpa-multiProject/blob/master/common/src/main/java/mh/dev/blog/multi/common/config/DatabaseConfiguration.java

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to Stackoverflow and also Spring framework, I'm just learning it through video tutorials. Thank you.

Comment: I got the answer from your link, I think I need to go with Spring conventions first over custom, because I'm a beginner.

Comment: Would advice you to do this. The link is from a demo project how to configure the entitymanager when you have more than one project sharing the data model. Which is probably not the case for you. You may check out the following which is a simpel command line runner spring app. The spring boot version used their is relatively old and the SpringBootApplication annotation did not exist at that time but it should match your needs beside that --> https://github.com/mh-dev/blog_springBoot-commandLine
At the top in the repo is a link to the blog entry of this demo project.